# How to create a NoneType Error workaround occurring within a functional input with occasional nonetype set

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I have a situation whereby the data set feeding into the code is creating a NoneType error. After attempting a couple of variations to workaround the error, I am not sure how revise the code to do so. Here is the trace back.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\anoth\test.py", line 64, in <module>
    pretty_print(master)
  File "A:\anoth\\test.py", line 53, in pretty_print
    categories = find_elms(soup, 'div', {'id': 'categories'})
  File "A:\anoth\\test.py", line 37, in find_elms
    for region in regions:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The following if-then loop has not worked when the NoneType data enters the code.

```
regions = soup.find(tag, attribute)
print('this ' + str(regions))
for region in regions: #this works for portions of the data set
    if [elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')] is None:
        return [] 
    else:
        return [elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')]

return []
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what form does your data have? and what type of object is `regions`expected to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doen't work is because `regions` at some point is None, and you are trying to iterate over None in your `for` loop, hence the error `'NoneType' object is not iterable`

```
regions = soup.find(tag, attribute)  #<------ this is returning None
print('this ' + str(regions))
for region in regions: #<-- you can't take a region in regions, when regions is None
    if [elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')] is None:
        return [] 
    else:
        return [elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')]

return []
```

You can add a `try except` in there:

```
try:
    regions = soup.find(tag, attribute)
    print('this ' + str(regions))
    for region in regions: #this works for portions of the data set
        if [elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')] == []:
            return [] 
        else:
            return [elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')]

except:
    print ('regions is NoneType object')
    return []
```

Comment: You can't do identity check in here: `[elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')] is []`, use `[elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')] == []`, or better just `not [elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')]` i.e. falsey check.

Comment: You've basically written: `if [] == []: return []`. If the list comprehension was written well, this would not be necessary. If `regions.find_all('a')` returns `None` this will still throw an exception.

Comment: Actually, it works. With the find and findall functions, the NoneType creates an attribute error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, regions might be `None`, so you need to check for that:

```
if regions:
    for region in regions:
        # do stuff
```

The next line is problematic as well:

```
if [elm.text for elm in regions.find_all('a')] is None:
```

A list comprehension will never return `None`. On the other hand, if `regions.find_all('a')` returns `None` you'll get the same error.  So try:

```
region_a_tags = regions.find_all('a')
if region_a_tags:
    return [elm.text for elm in region_a_tags]
else:
    return []
```

Comment: BS4 is sneaky tricky; this is the same for .find_all()  File "A:\anoth\\test.py", line 37, in find_elms
    regions_a_tags = regions.find('a')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: Just keep checking for `None` every time you use the `find` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
if regions:
  for region in regions:
      if some_thing_is_true_about_the_region:
          do_some_thing 
      else:
         do_some_thing_else 
else:
  do_some_thing_for_none_regions
```

Comment: While the code may solve OP's problem (untested), code only answers are discouraged on SO. It would be more helpful to explain where OP went wrong, and what your code is doing to fix this.